# precedence and execution of the operators in the statement

Tags: c, boolean, operator-precedence

can't understand how the boolean variable "check" is assigned 1 or 0. here 2 == 2 is true but the 2 is not equal to 3 so it should be false.....

```
/* practicing the precedence of assignment operator */

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    _Bool check;
    check = (2 == 2 != 3);

    printf("the value of _Bool is %d\n",check);


    return 0;
}
```

i expect the result to be false

Comment: `2==2` is `true` then `true != 3` -->`true`

Answer (score 1):

What actually happens is like this

```
(2 == 2 != 3)
```

becomes

```
(2 == 2) != 3)
```

which is

```
(1 != 3)
```

which in turn becomes

```
(1)
```

Perhaps what you needed was

```
(2 == 2 && 2 != 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- The equality operators have [**same precedence and left to right associativity**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), so `(2 ==2 != 3)` is the same as `((2 == 2) != 3)` which is `(1 != 3)` which is true.
- The equality operations return an `int` value as result, so using a `_Bool` (or, `bool` with `stdbool.h`) is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Operator *precedence* is the same for `==` and `!=`, since they both belong to the same group equality operators. To separate operators with same precedence, we use *operator associativity* of that group, in this case left-to-right. Meaning that `2 == 2 != 3` is guaranteed to be parsed as `(2 == 2) != 3`. So we get:

- `2 == 2` -> `1`
- `1 != 3` -> `1`

Notably both `==` and `!=` have higher precedence than `=`, so the parenthesis in your expression `= (2 == 2 != 3)` isn't needed (but good practice to use if you are uncertain about precedence).

---

Regarding *order of execution/evaluation*, that's another term not to confuse with operator precedence. The order of evaluation of the `==` and `!=` operands in your expression is unspecified, meaning we can't know which one that will get executed first.

In this case it doesn't matter, but if we had this `check = a() == b() != c();`, it could have. Here, we can't know which of the 3 functions that are executed first. We only know that operator precedence says that the result of `a` should be compared with the result of `b` before the result of `c`, but the function `c` may still be executed first.